# Can a glass plate act like a lens?

Tags: raytracing, pathtracing, global-illumination, refraction

I am trying to implement rough dielectrics on my renderer. I compared the results of my renderer and Mitsuba renderer. However, a thin glass plate which is a cube scaled by (0.4, 0.4, 0.01) magnifies the object in front of it in Mitsuba while it does not magnify in my renderer. Do I miss something or does Mitsuba renderer do something wrong?

edit: IOR of glass is 1.1 and outside is air.

Result of my renderer:
[image: Result of my renderer]

Result of mitsuba:
[image: Result of mitsuba]

Comment: A thin glass plate should not magnify like this (if it did, you would see this every time you look through a window in real life!). Could you share how the glass plate is set up in your Mitsuba scene file? Perhaps there's something off about it.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BHOzY16NYf9h2aYsGTb3ZpRiSlVTwf88/) it is

Comment: Just a side note: IoR of 1.1 is a heavily unrealistic value for glass, which is typically in interval 1.5-1.6 causing much stronger refraction effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `box.obj` file has no vertex normals, and by default Mitsuba will generate smooth normals for OBJ files that don't specify their own normals. This creates the magnification effect: the box with smooth normals forms a convex lens!

By adding this line to the box object in the scene file:

```
<boolean name="faceNormals" value="true"/>
```

I got results that look equivalent to yours:

[image: Mitsuba render with face normals]